# Drawing triangle in XML

Tags: android

In XML I'm attempting to draw a drop down triangle to be used as a background for a button but cant seem to get my head round the rotate XML tags.

Here's my XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="80%"
            android:pivotY="20%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid
                    android:color="#FFCC00" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And here's the outcome of the XML:

[image]

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i can draw triangle shape using XML 
**`triangle .xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%"
        android:toDegrees="45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#00000000" />

            <solid android:color="#00ACED" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: triangle]

Comment: I'm getting a random shape, nothing like you show here

Comment: @feresr i have used in my project and its working fine i don't know what wrong with you ? its same as image

Comment: Wierd. All I get is a strange looking shape, nothing like a triangle.:/

Comment: i have test double test right now its show as image,try this - you can give size 200 dp X 200dp to view

Comment: Ok. Must be a problem on my side then. I have revoked my downvote. Sorry about that. Thanks

Comment: if you rotate this triangle clockwise by 45 degrees, then put it in a RelativeLayout with alignParentRight and alignParentTop, it never ends up flush in the corner :(

Answer (score 4):

Try out the Below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="90%"
            android:pivotY="-50%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#ffffff"  />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: @ArMo 372Play with rotate properties as below..                                     android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="270%"
            android:pivotY="70%"  up facing trangle