# create drawable shape of right angled triangle

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I am trying to find out how to use drawable xml (`<shape>`) to create a right angled triangle like below (but fill with color without the black line):

[image]

I try to think from the angle of halving a rectangle from diagonal line, but still...can't find how to achieve it.

Is it doable with Android drawable xml?

Comment: Take one `TextView` in xml and set its value in java file like this:   `textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#9654;"));`

Comment: But I need to use it as a brackground for another view. Use TextView trick doesn't work for that purpose. I need it as a drawable resource.

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080396/drawing-triangle-in-xml and modified as you want.

Comment: Kindly have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

#### Create your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ul_ts.emvsdktester.drawabletraining.Main10Activity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape6"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Create my_shape6.xml inside the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#32c2b6"
        android:pathData="M0 20 L100 0 L100 20 Z"
        android:strokeColor="#9a1616" />

</vector>
```

#### The result

[image]